# Need help fixing the output of this Higher Order Function.

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, fizzbuzz

```
function each(arr, fn) {
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    fn(arr[i]);
    }
}


each([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], function(val){
if((val % 3) === 0){
    console.log(val + " fizz");
    } else if((val % 5) === 0) {
    console.log(val + " buzz");
    } else if((val % 15) === 0){
    console.log(val + " fizzbuzz");        
    } else {
    console.log(val);
    }
});
```

I am trying to get "fizzbuzz" to show up on the 15th element. I'm unsure of what to change to fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check for `% 15` first, not last

Comment: For any n such that  `n % 15 = 0` it's also true the `n % 5 == 0` and `n % 3 == 0` because 5 and 3 are factors of 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really what you asked, so take it for what it's worth. But since you are looking at higher-order functions, which are generally a feature of functional styles, you might consider taking a functional approach here.

For example you don't need all the loops and `if/then`s. Your `each` function is almost identical to `array.map`. And your `if`s are testing against a set of values, so you could just use `filter`. Also, when you do this, you will notice that you don't need to check `val % 15` because you are already checking 3 and 5:

```js
function each(arr, fn) { arr.map(fn) } // this is a bit redundanct but I left it to show why
          
each([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], function(val){
    let words = [
        {n: 3, text: 'fizz'},
        {n: 5, text: 'buzz'},   
    ]
    // now just filter the words array and use reduce to build your string
    let text = words.filter(w => !(val % w.n))
               .reduce((a, item) => a + item.text  , `${val}: ` )
 
    console.log(text)
        
})
```

It's a different style that takes some getting used to (and it's not always faster), but it has less noise and fits well with other higher order functions.

Comment: reduce instead of join, a bit overengineered.

Comment: I appreciate the comment @NinaScholz, but I’m  having trouble seeing how I would use join to replace reduce here.

Comment: `\`${val}: \` + words.filter(w => !(val % w.n)).join('');`

Comment: @NinaScholz `words.filter()` returns an array of objects not strings.

Comment: then add a map for the values.

Comment: @NinaScholz  Okay, `map()` plus `join()` would work. It's doesn't seem less-engineered to me than just using `reduce()`, however.  I could see that it might be more readable, though.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in comments, `3` and `5` both are factors of `15` so you have to put `(val%15)` first otherwise control will never reach to that statement.
ex. on 15th element, `(val%3)===0` will become true and only `" fizz"` will be logged.

```
function each(arr, fn) {
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    fn(arr[i]);
    }
}


each([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], function(val){
    if((val % 15) === 0){
        console.log(val + " fizzbuzz");
    } else if((val % 5) === 0) {
        console.log(val + " buzz");
    } else if((val % 3) === 0){
        console.log(val + " fizz");        
    } else {
        console.log(val);
    }
});
```